# ApplicationContext get annotated bean by name

Tags: spring

Tried to search for an answer - no luck, so posting a question.

I have

```
@ConfigurationProperties
class XYZConfig {
    int f1....
}
```

I'm trying later to get this bean by name in my application, but the only one name available is a fully qualified one. I tried to use `@Component(value="xyzconfig")` no luck either

I wonder if there is a way to set a short name for the bean without going into xml and specifying it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what are you trying but if you class `XYZConfig` should be configuration class and there will be created beans than you need to annotate this class with @Configuration. Also in your context .xml file you need to add `<annotation-driven/>` and set `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.wit.classes.for.scanning"></context:component-scan>`.

But, if this class really has to be Bean then create simple java class (i.e.: `BeanClass`) and later in your configuration create method like this:

```
@Bean
public BeanClass beanClassName(){
BeanClass bc = new BeanClass()
...
return bc;
```

Later this bean will be visible with id/name `beanClassName`

Comment: XYZConfig is a type-safe configuration for application.properties. I didn't declare it as a bean in config.xml, but I use it later as `@EnableConfigurationProperties(XYZConfig.class) class XYZ { .... }` So it's not a configuration in terms of Spring, I guess. I found a workaround getting bean for XYZ and reaching XYZConfig from it (XYZ has a member of XYZConfig type)

Comment: I didn't know about that way to include property values before, I did it through .xml configuration. 
Do you really need to find that bean by name. @Autowired should help.
Look at this link: https://spring.io/blog/2013/10/30/empowering-your-apps-with-spring-boot-s-property-support .

Comment: Yeah, I know about `@Autowire` and it works fine in other places. The thing is I need to reach this bean from a code which can't use `@Autowire`